# How can I run a python file on a mac, but make it so the person running it can't see the code

Tags: python, macos, py2app

So I have created a python program that works on mac when I run it in VS code. But I want to distribute it. I have tried the py2app function but that doesn't work because i have to import the PyKeyboard function for the program. (For keystrokes) I am trying to port it onto mac so that I can have the user run the program without seeing the code. I have tried it with py2app but since there is no GUI it doesn't work.

I don't have any code, but yea.

Comment: Try PyInstaller, or not caring that the user can see the code, or making a web app where the code stays on the server.

Comment: I'm not familiar with py2app, but I'd be very surprised if it doesn't support bundling third-party modules.

Comment: @Chris i think you could but it has issues with the way it runs. Cause there is no GUI

Comment: "it has issues with the way it runs. Cause there is no GUI"—this has literally nothing to do with the question you asked. Are you trying to ask about packaging, or about how to build a GUI for your code? Please read [ask].

Comment: @Chris what I meant is that I have tried to bundle it with the py2app but since there is no GUI it has issues.

Comment: Is there a *reason* you are concerned about the user seeing the code?

Comment: @RyanVogel, I suggest you ask a question specifically about the issues you're having with py2app.

Comment: @chepner The code isn't really open source code. I want it locked down (pretty much)

Comment: Python was probably a poor choice for implementing your project, then.